# Java sockets: Client 'calling an object' on the server? (Like with C# WCF)

Tags: java, sockets

I have no experience with Java network programming, I have a fair bit of experience with C# networking though.

Anyway we have a software project in college and its basically an instant messenger using client and server. The lecturer was talking about how the client interacts with the server and he was explaining about an object that the client would receive from the server and use to make requests.

This sounds very like C# WCF to me where the client gets a server object that and makes calls on it to interact with the server. So is there a similar class/library for Java? Something that lets a client interact with a server by means of making calls on a server object?

Comment: Sounds more like they are just Serializing the object, sending it over the stream, and deserializing it? Does that sound right?

Answer (score 1):

Generally you have 4+ options.

1. Use plain sockets and custom protocol on to of TCP. Implement your own mechanism of serialization/desearialization. So, object of class `MyMessage` will be serialized to something like `MSG:hello`. This string will be sent over network. Other side will parse it and create instance of object `MyMessage` that is a "copy" of source object.
2. Use built in java serialization mechanism. Class instances of which you are going to send over network must implememnt tag interface `Serializable`. There are a lot of references concerning using of serialization.
3. Use RMI. It allows you to call method that will run in address space of other process.
4. Use web service (SOAP based or RESTfull)

A lot of other options are available. I hope these tips will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

He could be talking about [RMI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/index.html). See the [Hello World!](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/hello/hello-world.html) tutorial for a quick introduction.